# Display thymeleaf fragment on checkbox click or checked

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have form which has some checkbox. I want to display a fragment when I user click (checked) on checkbox.

Is there a way in Thymeleaf by using any th:* function or how Can I display fragment in thymeleaf on checkbox click.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your requirements...

1. Create a simple JavaScript handler on checkbox click event and submit your form with some parameter/hidden value. When the server handles "onSubmit" request, check this value and if chackbox was chacked, render view (Thymeleaf template) with included additional fragment. Vise versa when checkbox is unchecked render view without this fragment. This solution is not ideal as your server will get hits every time the user checks ckeckbox.
2. Always render the view with the fragment included into the page. By default hide top-level fragment element with style `display:none;`. create a simple JavaScript handler on checkbox click event and toggle this style from `none` to `block` and vise-versa. This solution works completely in the user's browser and doesn't require to submit to your server.